# Serialising classes that implement List<T> for transferring over WCF

Tags: wcf, class, serialization, collections, inheritance

I have spent some time writing code for my application assuming that the serialisation bit would be the easiest part of it. Pretty much both sides (client and server) are done and all I need to do is passing a class AccountInfo from the service to the client... 
The problem is that AccountInfo inherits List and therefore [DataContract] attribute is not valid. 
I tried using the [CollectionDataContract] attribute but then the class that is received on the other side (client) contains only generic List methods without my custom implemented properties such as GroupTitle...
I have worked out a solution for this problem but I don't know how to apply it.

Basically everything works when I make a property instead of inheriting a List but then I can't bind this class to LongListSelector (WP7) because it's not a collection type.

There are three classes I'm on about. 
AccountInfo that contains multiple instances of: 
AccountInfoGroup that contains multiple instances of:
AccountInfoEntry (this one does not inherit list therefore there are no problems serialising it and all properties are accessible).

Could someone help me using right attributes to serialise and transfer these classes using a WCF method?

Here is the code of 2 of these collection classes:

```
public class AccountInfo : List<AccountInfoGroup>
    {
        public AccountInfo()
        {
            UpdateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
            EntryID = Guid.NewGuid();
        }

        public bool HasItems
        {
            get
            {
                return (Count != 0);
            }
            private set
            {
            }
        }
        public Guid EntryID
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public decimal GetTotalCredit()
        {
            decimal credit = 0;
            foreach (AccountInfoGroup acg in this.Where(item => item.Class == AccountInfoEntry.EntryType.Credit))
            {
                acg.Where(item => item.ItemClass == AccountInfoEntry.EntryType.Credit).ToList().ForEach(entry => 
                { credit += entry.Remaining; }
                );
            }
            return credit;
        }
        public bool UsedForCreditComparison = false;
        public DateTime UpdateTime { get; private set; }
    }

    public class AccountInfoGroup : List<AccountInfoEntry>
    {
        public AccountInfoEntry.EntryType Class 
        {
            get;
            private set;
       }
        public string Title
        {
            get
            {
                return AccountInfoEntry.ClassToString(Class);
            }
        }

        public AccountInfoGroup(AccountInfoEntry.EntryType groupClass)
        {
            this.@Class = groupClass;
        }

        public bool HasItems
        {
            get
            {
                return (Count != 0);
            }
            private set
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

Thank you for any suggestions... :)

Answer (score 0):

The sample you had is quite painful for WCF in serialization.
What I suggest is you to revised and have a common models for your WCF messages (That means it only contains properties with getter and setter, serialization attributes).

If you have a problem in LongListSelector binding in WP7, you might want to convert the message to the actual type the WP7 object supports to use in binding.

Comment: I don't quite get what you exactly mean by common models... I'm brand new to WCF and I was sure this wouldn't be a problem.
These classes bind perfectly to LongListSelector but there is no way I know to send them over WCF...

Comment: That is actually your answer you said: "These classes bind perfectly to LongListSelector... no way... to send ... over WCF".

Basically, your WCF has its own request/response objects (messages) and in your WP7 application you have this set of objects that is perfectly bind to LongListSelector.  Now what you need to do is convert the response object from WCF to your object in WP7 application to perfectly bind to LongListSelector.